# 500 Internal Server Error!! - Issue in wsgi in django application migrating from python2.7 to python3.6

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error when I migrated my django app from python2.7 to python3.6. I have created a new virtualenv, and created all the apps individually. The virtualenv is defined in uwsgi.ini file

`home    =       /home/netadc/.venvs1/netadc`

I have installed all the packages using pip3.6. I am not sure what I am missing. Every config in uwsgi is same as python2.7 when it was working.I am using uwsgi 2.0.13. I have restarted nginx as well. Is there a separate uwsgi for python3 which I cannot locate? The socket permissions are also same as before. Please help.

The command to start wsgi is :-
`/home/netadc/.venvs1/netadc/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/netadc/apps/netadc/netadc/uwsgi/netadc_uwsgi.ini --enable-threads`

In wsgi logs, i see :-
`--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 13634|app: -1|req: -1/3] x.x.x.x () {42 vars in 1029 bytes} [Mon Dec 17 09:04:40 2018] GET /netadc/home => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500)`

The access logs in nginx show :-
`x.x.x.x - - [17/Dec/2018:09:05:43 -0700] "GET /netadc/home HTTP/1.1" 500 32`

Nothing comes up in nginx error logs.

When I do manage.py shell, I see :-
`ImportError: bad magic number in 'lib': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'`

I removed all the .pyc files, but then sometimes manage.py shell hangs up and sometimes it opens fine. But again after sometime, I will get the magic number error as above.

When I revert the virtualenv back to my previous virtualenv in the uwsgi.ini file which uses python2.7, I get some error logs on uwsgi.

`home    =       /home/netadc/.venvs/netadc`
Log :-
`File "./ivpn/rest_appviewx.py", line 29
    print('Server IP has NAT already. So no QIP update needed.', end=' ')
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

My uwsgi ini file :-

```
[uwsgi]

#uid    =       nginx
#gid    =       nginx

# Django-related settings
env     =       HTTPS=on

# the base directory (full path)
chdir   =       /home/netadc/apps/netadc

# Django's wsgi file
module  =       netadc.wsgi

# the virtualenv (full path)
home    =       /home/netadc/.venvs1/netadc

pythonpath = /home/netadc/.venvs1/netadc/bin/python3.6
PythonHome = /home/netadc/.venvs1/netadc/


# master
master   =      true

# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10

buffer-size =   65536

# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket  = /home/netadc/apps/netadc/netadc/uwsgi/tmp/netadc.sock

# read post data by default
post-buffering  =   1

# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
#chmod-socket    = 666

# daemonize
daemonize       =       true

# logging
logger  =       
file:/home/netadc/apps/netadc/netadc/uwsgi/tmp/netadc_uwsgi.log

# clear environment on exit
vacuum  =       true
```

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Comment: Open nginx, gunicorn, django error log files, find the error message(s) and add it to the question.

Comment: Please paste the configuration or command you're using, as well as the error messages you get.

Comment: @Evhz added the logs on my original post.

Comment: I start getting uwsgi logs when I move back to my previous virtualenv. I configured the new virtualenv using python3 and every install was using pip3.6 and python3.6, so I am not sure what is causing the issue. Added some point on my original question.

Comment: I am not using gunicorn. Using nginx + wsgi with my django application. Added the configuration or command on my original post.

Comment: @chris posted the ini file to original post.

Comment: @ivan starostin posted the ini file to original post

Comment: @Evhz posted the ini file to original post